# Selecting elements of a matrix that meet certain criteria of another matrix without for-loops

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a matrix with market capitalizations of companies  (MCap).
I have a second matrix with the corresponding returns of these companies (Ret).

First I get the 90%-decile of market capitalization of each row with the command:

```
dec <- apply(MCap, 2, function(x){quantile(x, probs=.9, na.rm=T)})
```

My goal is to get a matrix with the returns (from Ret) of those companies, which exceed the 90%-decile market capitalization (dec) of their row.

Step1:
I create a matrix with zeros and ones if the market cap exceed the 90%-decil of the row

```
for (i in 1:n){
  Ret.interim[,i] <- MCap[,i]>=dec[i]
}
```

Step2:
Then I multiply this new matrix (Ret.interim) with the Ret-Matrix to get the Returns I am looking for.

```
Ret.final <- Ret.interim*Ret
Ret.final[Ret.new==0] <- NA
```

**Is there a way to avoid the for-loop in Step1?**
Can it be replaced by an apply-type function?
Or can Step1 and Step2 even be merged into one Step?

The for loop can maybe be replaced, but the "benchmark" dec[i] changes with each row.

Thank you for your help in advance :-)

Edit:
Some random data to test the code:

```
MCap <- sample(x=300:500, size=25, replace=T)
MCap <- matrix(MVe, nrow=5, ncol=5)

Ret <- runif(25, min=-1, max=1)
Ret <- matrix(Ret, nrow=5, ncol=5)
```

Comment: Maybe `Ret.interim[] <- MCap[]>= matrix(rep(dec,times=nrow(MCap))` ?

Comment: Error in MVe[] >= matrix(rep(dec1.mve.new, times = nrow(MVe))) : 
  non-conformable arrays